# LotusScript GetDocumentByURL not authenticating in scheduled agent

Tags: http, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a LotusScript agent that works manually when run from the Notes client menu but fails when run as a scheduled agent on the server.  The agent gets a web page using the `GetDocumentByURL` method.

```
url$="http://example.com/notesdb.nsf/XAgent.xsp?documentId="+ Quotesdoc.Universalid +"&action=openDocument&login"

Print("url "+ url$)

Set doc = db.GetDocumentByURL(url$, 1, , , "username", "password")
Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem( "Body" )
body$ = rtitem.text

Print("status "+body$)
```

From the Notes client, the agent will authenticate and return a JSON object.  But from a scheduled agent on the server, the authentication appears to fail as the response is 200, login failed.

The Web Retriever service is running, and the web.nsf db has a Cookies view, but the server log shows:

```
11/13/2018 07:07:36 PM  AMgr: Agent ('Scheduled Agent' in 'mail\mailer.nsf') printing: url http://example.com/notesdb.nsf/XAgent.xsp?documentId=61D46EE586868DBA85256C84005414B9&action=openDocument&login
11/13/2018 07:07:36 PM  WEB(3): Unable to find design note for view 'Cookies': Entry not found in index
11/13/2018 07:07:36 PM  AMgr: Agent ('Scheduled Agent' in 'mail\mailer.nsf') printing: status Forgot password?
```

My guess is that the SessionID is not being passed via a cookie and the authentication is failing.  Ideas?

Comment: Do you have a view "Cookies" in your DB object ?

Comment: this method imho is built to be used in context with the Server Web Navigator database. Is the Web Navigator retrieval process running on your machine? - also I find it curious that your URL ends with "&login"; this usually pops up a login dialog or login page depending on the way you set up your Domino server

Comment: I don't think I've seen getDocumentByURL used in 15 years. If you're running on Windows, is there a reason you're going that way rather than using XmlHttpRequest instead?

Comment: Or for that matter, why not access the database using the regular Notes classes?  That way signatures and authentication and such are already handled.

Comment: I'm calling an XPage to run a java program that will not work with LS2J in LotusScript.  I've decided to go with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719192/get-a-field-value-from-a-webpage-lotusscript using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP